# Integrating Spark with Elasticsearch

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to send sparkdataframe to Elasticsearch cluster. I have Spark dataframe(df).

I created index = "spark" but, when I ran this command:

```
   df.write
     .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
     .option("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
     .option("es.port","9092")
     .option("es.net.ssl","true")
     .option("es.nodes", "localhost")
     .save("spark/docs")
```

I came across this error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o144.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
```

Spark version: spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7

Elasticsearch version: elasticsearch-7.7.0

Dependencies added: elasticsearch-hadoop-7.7.0.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should to specify `es.resource` on write, format can be specified as `es`. The below worked for me on `Spark 2.4.5` (running on `docker`) and ES version 7.5.1. First of all, make sure you're running `pyspark` with the following package:

```
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS --packages org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:7.5.1 pyspark-shell
```

On PySpark side, for example in a notebook:

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local").setAppName("ES Test")
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
conf.set("es.nodes", "elasticsearch")  # name of my docker container, you might keep localhost
conf.set("es.port", "9200")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

colnames = [('col_' + str(i+1)) for i in range(11)]
df1 = spark._sc.parallelize([
  [it for it in range(11)], 
  [it for it in range(1,12)]]
).toDF((colnames))

(
  df1
  .write
  .format('es')
  .option(
    'es.resource', '%s/%s' % ('<resource_name>', '<table_name>'))
  .save()
)
```

Additonal - Verified this was written using `elasticsearch` Python package:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
esclient = Elasticsearch(['elasticsearch:9200'])


response = esclient.search(
    index='<resource_name>*',
    body={
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "col1": 1
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "test_agg": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "col1",
                    "size": 10
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```